# Autocomplete() class not displaying all items in list

Tags: flutter, arraylist, autocomplete

I have a `List<String>[]` that has a single list of items as below:

```dart
List<String> food = <String> [
  "Apple",
  "Banana",
  "Orange",
  …
];
```

It has 900+ items (Not sure if that's relevant).

I am using the [Autocomplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html#:%7E:text=Autocomplete%20class%20Null%20safety,built%20with%20the%20fieldViewBuilder%20parameter.) class.

```dart
Autocomplete<String>(
  optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
    if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
      return const Iterable<String>.empty();
    }
    return food.where((String option) {
      return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
    });
  },
  onSelected: (String selection) {
    debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
  },
),
```

However, it only shows some items in the list and not all the items when typing. Example, if I type `B`, all `List` items show and are scrollable but if I type `ban`, `banana` does not show up.

Any idea why it's doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not matching because your `options` are first letter uppercase, and you parse your typed text to lowercase. So try to parse the `option` to lowercase and then check does it match, like this:

```
return food.where((String option) {
  return option.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
});
```